# Cake php css load issue on apache2

Tags: cakephp, ubuntu, installation

My `css` file is not loading.

I have just installed apache2 with `php` on `ubuntu`. (Mysql server already installed.)

I have placed fresh download of cake `php` from official site. But when I am trying to access it, `CSS` file is not loaded.

Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting these files:

```
 /.htaccess
 /app/.htaccess
 /app/webroot/.htaccess
```

and uncommenting this line on app/config/core.php [69]

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

EDIT:

to answer your comment: as far as I know, what this does is set the base url of the app to index.php ([env()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/701/env) Gets an environment variable from available sources) That baseUrl is used to rewrite the urls without using mod_rewitte, with [pathinfo](http://www.tutorio.com/tutorial/php-alternative-to-mod-rewrite-for-se-friendly-urls).

Comment: cool.. worked.. can u explain me the line u uncommented. I am just new to cakephp. Worked on php last year and working on rails.

Comment: doing this means that you will not have 'seo urls' instead have index.php/... you should have just done sudo a2enmod rewrite or something similar

Answer (score 4):

I would think telling him to read the instructions and setup requirements including the use of mod_rewrite would be a better solution than pointing him towards the no mod_rewrite method.

A quick google for mod_rewrite apache ubuntu brings up a ton of possibly useful information and will likely work out for him better than turning off one of Cake's key features.

Comment: Maybe so, I assumed that in a developing environment pretty URLs weren't all that important. What he wanted was to get his css loading, so I gave him information on doing that, the quickest way I knew how. Maybe it wasn't the best way, if he was asking about a production install, I probably would have given him both alternatives. As I said, I didn't think it using mod_rewrite was so necessary in a development environment, if later he wanted to enable it, he just needs to paste four files and comment one line in the config. Anyway, I'll keep what you said in mind if anyone asks again about this

Comment: Don't get me wrong - your answer was correct and good - I just think in 2 weeks when he can't get routing working or goes into production etc that he will just have to ask a slightly different question for us to answer again. Especially since it should be as simple for him as uncommenting the mod_rewrite.so reference in his apache config.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue when the .htaccess is missing from the root or from webroot.  Usually, this occurs when adding files to svn and the .htaccess is not included.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add

to enable mod_rewrite with apache on ubuntu

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```